# Hide Javascript file from Analytics

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, optimization, google-analytics

I apologize ahead of time for the non descriptive title, as I wasn't really sure how to word this.

I've currently switched some of my Wordpress sites that have a responsive design that implement a slider over to [WooSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/products/wooslider/).  Works super well, and I love it.  However, there is something stopping me from switching all of my sites over.  And I understand this is not a WooSlider only fault, but it's something I cannot Google and find out.

This is happening on every page view, even those without a slider.

In Google Analytics it shows `domain.com/?wooslider-javascript=load&t=1352743207&ver=1.0.0` as a page view.  For every single page.  I obviously don't want this, but I don't know how to get rid of it.

Another example of this happening is using Gravity Forms with a referrer info plugin that shows page views, search query, browser, etc.

When the form is sent, the following is sent via email.

```
Page visited 1: domain.com/?wooslider-javascript=load&t=1352743207&ver=1.0.0 (http://domain.com/?wooslider-javascript=load&t=1352743207&ver=1.0.0)
Page visited 2: domain.com/about (http://domain.com/contact/about/
Page visited 3: domain.com/?wooslider-javascript=load&t=1352751787&ver=1.0.0 (http://domain.com/?wooslider-javascript=load&t=1352751787&ver=1.0.0) 
Page visited 4: domain.com/contact/ (http://domain.com/contact/)
```

So obviously I don't want that js file to show up as a page view.  How can I remedy this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an SEO plugin like Yoast? If so, you might want to check  the settings in there.

Comment: I am not using any plugins other than WooSlider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Analytics Configuration Mistake #2: Query String Variables](http://cutroni.com/blog/2006/09/21/google-analytics-configuration-mistake-2-query-string-variables/)

`wooslider-javascript,t,ver`

Comment: Thank you.  This makes sense for Analytics.  Now I just need to figure out the Page Visited thing.